# Issue with bootstrap column height when second column has margin, padding, or wraps

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a breadcrumb-ish situation involving 2 columns, one column acts as the page heading (left), and the other contains the breadcrumbs (right). I am unable to get the first column to take up the full height when the second column - or the contents therein have any amount of margin or padding or if the column's contents (breadcrumbs) wrap.

I would like for the first column's height to be full regardless, so that the border between the columns is full, and the bar is placed centered on the bottom line. In it's default state, the look is achieved. Simply add a padding via class `py-5` to `#bread` to see the undesired behavior.

https://codepen.io/afagard/pen/yLpLKGr

Edit:

I think I figured it out. Seems a bit janky though so still accepting answers.

https://codepen.io/afagard/pen/wvpPzXg

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the same py-5 class to the parent div which contains these classes:

`border-dark border-end border-md-none col-md-3`

And remove the padding-top and padding-bottom from the child div with the class:

`header-wrapper`